# Can AWS Cognito Identity Pool redirect a user to external SAML IdP for login?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, saml

I want to use AWS Cognito Identity Pool to do this:

**If a user is not currently logged in with Identity Provider, I want Cognito to redirect the user to IdP login page (with SAMLRequest passed as GET param), then parse SAMLResponse for me. I assume there should be an AWS Cognito SDK method to initiate this redirection?**

I understand that User Pools can do this, but can it be done via Identity Pools?

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/saml-identity-provider.html#authenticate-user-with-saml) I read:

> To add support for your SAML identity provider in Amazon Cognito, you must first authenticate users with your SAML identity provider from your iOS or Android app. The code for integrating and authenticating with the SAML identity provider is specific to SAML providers. After your user is authenticated, you can provide the resulting SAML assertion to Amazon Cognito Identity using Amazon Cognito APIs.

This seems to tell that Identity Pools won't authenticate a user with an external provider for me. Then I wonder what's the reason to use them at all...